# I write an operator by asyncio, but how to call this asynchronous operator in python script?

Tags: python

```
import bpy
import concurrent.futures
import asyncio

# Define your asyncio coroutine
async def my_coroutine():
    # Your coroutine code here
    await bpy.ops.object.myoperator()
    

# Define a wrapper function to run the coroutine in a separate thread
def run_my_operator():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception=", e)
    finally:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        
    #asyncio.ensure_future(my_coroutine())
    #loop.create_task(my_coroutine())
    loop.run_until_complete(my_coroutine())
    

run_my_operator()
```

It raised error like as:
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\3.3\python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 577, in _check_running
raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hello. I think you'll have better luck with application timers, they're supported by Blender. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: Thank you! Will have a test!